# DB FitNesse test results update in TFS

Tags: database, tfs, fitnesse

Is there a way to link your DB Fitness tests to TFS? what I mean by that is when the tests are executed say via DBFit can the results be updated in TFS? would be grateful if you could put me in the write direction. I should really add that i do not mean checking tests in & out, but rather its status of the executed tests in DBFit

Comment: Do you want the results of any run from a fitnesse installation to the TFS server. Or would having TFS run the tests itself, say on a schedule or on test commit, and recording those results also be acceptable?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Here is a blog of Setting up FitNesse for Team Foundation Server, you may check whether it helps: http://blog.agilepartner.net/setting-up-fitnesse-for-team-foundation-server/

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT The link is broken...